# how to combine responsive images with signed urls

Tags: html, responsive-design, google-cloud-storage, responsive-images, pre-signed-url

I am using [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for images but also would like them to be responsive. Do I really need to sign all size versions of the picture? It seems more efficient if first the actual size that will be shown is determined so I only need to provide a signed url for that image. Is there a common approach for this?

So e.g. this html:

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

Would I need to sign all `elva-fairy` urls in the `srcset`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need a different signed URL for each unique image.  Signed URLs don't automatically resize or redirect to other objects in your storage bucket.

Comment: Well that's a nice concise answer, thanks. As the actual signing is done on my server with an encryption calculation (so not an api request towards Google), it will be a five-fold (different sizes) calculation now. Is this something to worry about, or are these calculations 'negligible' from a performance point of view...?

Comment: Actually, it would also be handy to have an event on the `img` element that gives the  actual 'chosen src' before it starts loading it. That does not exist?

Comment: Signed URLs are generated by Cloud Storage,  You simply invoke an API to generate one.

Comment: As stated before it is not in my case as I am using the [Algorithm for signing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#algorithm) URLs on my own server.

Comment: It sounds like should benchmark your own code then.

Comment: Yeah, will try and see what happens.